# Java: bound mismatch: error while using comparator

Tags: java, comparator

I was trying a small code using Comparator to sort list of student through there roll number. But I am getting compile time error at this line:

```
Collections.sort(l);
```

Below my test code:

```
     package test;

     import java.util*;


      public class StudentUsingComparator implements
                    Comparator<StudentUsingComparator> {

        int roll;
        String name;

        public StudentUsingComparator(int roll, String name) {
                    this.name = name;
                    this.roll = roll;
        }
        @Override
        public int compare(StudentUsingComparator s1, StudentUsingComparator s2) {
                    return s1.roll - s2.roll;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                StudentUsingComparator student1 = new StudentUsingComparator(10, "ab");
                StudentUsingComparator student2 = new StudentUsingComparator(30, "cd");
               StudentUsingComparator student3 = new StudentUsingComparator(20, "bc");

              List<StudentUsingComparator> l = new ArrayList<StudentUsingComparator>();
               l.add(student1);
               l.add(student2);
               l.add(student3);
               System.out.println("unsorted collection is:  " + l);
               Collections.sort(l);   //m getting error in this line
               System.out.println("sorted collection is:  " + l);
        }
   }
```

Error message says:

> bound mismatch: the generic method sort(List) of type collection is not applicable for the arguments list(). the inferred type StudentUsingComparator is not a valid substitute for  the bounded parameter>

Answer (score 2):

You confused `Comparable<>` and `Comparator<>`. Classes that have an intrinsic order should implement `Comparable<>`, then you can use `Collecections.sort(l)`. When you use `Collections.sort(l,c)`, `c` should implement `Comparator<>`, which defines an external ordering that is different and separate from the internal.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mixing two concepts:

1. You can define a `Student` class that implements `Comparable`, then you can use `Collections.sort(l)` to sort a `List<Student> l`.
2. In addition to your class `Student` (could be `Comparable` or not) you define an extra class implementing `Comparator<Student>` and use `Collections.sort(l,c)` with a `List<Student> l` and a `Comparator<Student> c`.

While it is possible in theory to mix the two cases (like you did) and make `Student` implement `Comparator<Student>` (and then continue along the lines of 2.) this is a total no-go because either your objects have a natural order - then you should go with `Comparable` and case 1., or they don't, then defining the order should go to a separate `Comparator`-class.